# Why would a c++ double be limiting itself to 5 decimal places?

Tags: c++, double

I'm hoping you can help with a bit of a head scratcher.

I have written out a template class to calculate standard deviations:

```
template <class T>
double GetStandardDeviation(T* valueArray, int populationSize)
{
    double average;
    T cumulativeValue = 0;
    double cumulativeSquaredDeviation = 0;
    // calculate average
    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
    {
        cumulativeValue += valueArray[i];
    }
    average = (double)cumulativeValue / (double)populationSize;
    // calculate S.D.
    for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
    {
        double difference = average - (double)valueArray[i];
        double squaredDifference = difference * difference;
        cumulativeSquaredDeviation += squaredDifference;
    }
    return cumulativeSquaredDeviation / (double)populationSize;

}
```

And this seems to be doing everything correctly, except it returns the result to only 5 decimal places.  Can anyone suggest a reason for this?  I'm stumped!

Comment: Doubles store as many decimal places as they have room for.

Comment: *How* do you check the number of decimals?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like `dp`. It took me chris' comment to understand that you meant "decimal places".

Comment: On a side note, I suggest using a container like `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a pointer and a size.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca, can you justify that assertion - if the array is of 'int' for instance, the division in 'average = (double)cumulativeValue / (double)populationSize;' would be an integer division without the type casts?

Comment: ***Why*** do you believe you are only getting 5 places?   I see no output in your program, and no other way to check.

Comment: Seems the question you should have asked is 'How do I get C++ to display more decimal places than the default?' Ask again, or read some documentation.

Comment: Change output stream precision.

Comment: @davmac This is indeed the only place where a cast is necessary, and only on the `cumulativeValue` part. If `cumulativeValue` was declared `double` instead of `T` then even this cast would be unnecessary.

Comment: @syam, there is also: `double difference = average - (double)valueArray[i];` - the `T` type might not be directly numeric, so I think the cast could be necessary here (i.e. the type defines a cast-to-double operator). In any case I think it's not correct that you don't need _all_ the typecasting.

Comment: @davmac Indeed, the cast would be necessary iif `T`'s `operator double()` is marked `explicit`. Didn't think about that, my bad.

Comment: @davmac I'm sorry, I must have mis-read the code... let's say it's because of post-lunch

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An IEEE-754 double precision value has about 15 decimal digits of precision so it will be limited to five decimal places only if your values are up around the tens of billions.

What you're most likely seeing is simply the default output format for doubles which, like C, will tend to give you a limited number of fractional digits.

You can see this in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main(void) {
    double d = 1.23456789012345;
    std::cout << d << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of which is:

```
1.23457
1.23456789012345
```

Table 89 in the C++03 standard (in `27.4.4.1 basic_ios constructors`) shows the post-conditions after calling `basic_ios::init()` and it shows the default precision to be 6. In C++11, it says the same thing, only in table 128 under `27.5.5.2 basic_ios constructors`.

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed the issue.